# Which file is bootable within a given iso

Tags: bootable, mkisofs

Given a particular bootable iso or cdrom, how can I determine which file inside it is the one that gets called on booting from the image?  Put differently, assuming that the iso had been generated using mkisofs, how can I know which file was passed to mkisofs using the -b option?

Comment: Read Wikipedia on Power On Self Test and Boot.